# Проблема с запуском программы C#

Tags: c#, .net

Запускаю программу **.net**[image: введите сюда описание изображения] через `dotnet run -p service.dll`
Выдает такую ошибку, так понимаю надо фиксить проблему в коде, но код в файле машинный, что делать?

Comment: `dotnet run` - запускает **исходный** код

Comment: И Вам прямо написано: не удалось найти файл проекта. А он Вам и не нужен

Comment: Просто `dotnet service.dll`

Comment: (И код в файле не совсем машинный, кстати говоря. Да, IL можно назвать кодом виртуальной IL-машины, но обычно под машинным кодом подразумевается непосредственно код, понимаемый вашей физической машиной)